# How to optimize eloquent query which has a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables Tags and Admin , my tags table looks like the following:

[image]

And my admin table looks like the following:

[image]

The tag field in the admin table is a foreign key, and it references the ID in the tags table. What i wanted to do is , pull up the records in the admin table with a specific `tag`, now ofcourse the `tag` in the admin table references the `id` in the `tags` table.

So i have written the below query to retrieve the articles from the admin table , that have a specific tag(eg. `Javascript`).

```
public function showTagListing($tag) {
        $tagId = DB::table('tags')->where('tag', $tag)->first();
        $tagBlogList = DB::table('admin')->where('tag', $tagId->id )->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->get();
        return view('pages.taglisting', compact('tagBlogList', $tagBlogList));
    }
```

I think i have written a few extra unneeded lines of code here for retrieving the article records , how can i make the code in one line ? How can i optimize these lines of code ?

Comment: In terms of performance optimization you can't do much more. You could do a join instead of 2 queries (which is most cases should perform better). But in term of maintainability and code niceness you could do a lot. To start you should create [models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) for each of your db tables and create relationships between them accordingly (ie Admin belongsTo Tag, Tag has many Admin...).

Comment: Actually from performance level you should be able to do exactly this with 1 query without a join, using `WHERE EXISTS (...)` - for how to do it with eloquent you can see Sandeesh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some trickery to derive the `$tag` through dependency injection and resolve it by another column other than the `primary key` by adding some logic to the `boot` method of your `RouteServiceProvider`

```
Route::bind('tag', function ($value) {
    if (is_int($value)) {
        return App\Tag::findOrFail($value);
    } else {
        return App\Tag::where('tag', $value)->firstOrFail();
    }
});
```

Then you can change your route so that it expects a tag instance, regardless of `primary key integer` or a `tag string`:

```
//no idea how your route looks, but the important part is {tag}
Route::get('/show-tag-listing/{tag}', 'TagController@showTagListing');
```

Finally, update your function to resolve the tag through Dependency Injection:

```
public function showTagListing(App\Tag $tag) {
```

Now you no longer need the `$tagId =`, you can just use `$tag->id` later.

You can also make sure you have your relationships established in the model files. Because you have the `tag_id` on the admin table, the `$tag` will have many admin records, and the `admin` will `haveOne` tag, like this:

```
// App\Tag class

public function admins()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Admin');
}

// App\Admin class

public function tag()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
}
```

Now instead of doing:

```
$tagBlogList = DB::table('admin')->where('tag', $tagId->id )->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->get();
```

You can do:

```
$tagBlogList = $tag->admins()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Few things to note. Use `findOrFail` and `FirstOrFail` instead when using model binding so that it throws a 404 before reaching the controller and failing. `$tagBlogList = $tag->load('admins')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();` will return the tag with the blogs as a related object. `$tagBlogList = $tag->admins()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();` should do what's desired.

Comment: @Sandeesh Yup, good points. Updated to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function showTagListing($tag)
{
    $tagBlogList = DB::table('admin')
        ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'admin.tag')
        ->where('tags.tag', $tag)
        ->latest()
        ->select('admin.*')
        ->get();

    return view('pages.taglisting', compact('tagBlogList'));
}
```

If you want to go the Eloquent way then you can do this. Create the appropriate model with relationship.

```
public function showTagListing($tag)
{
    $tagBlogList = Admin::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use($tag) {
            $query->where('tag', $tag);
        })
        ->latest()
        ->get();

    return view('pages.taglisting', compact('tagBlogList'));
}
```